# I forgot my PuzzlingCard PIN

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Oh guys... I'm in front of an ATM and want to withdraw some money, but I forgot my 4 digit PIN. Can somebody help me out?

I have a backup card with 6x6 fields, each field has exactly one character!

```
    - A B C D -
    A - 1 1 3 G
    B 9 - 1 2 C
    C 9 1 - 1 D
    D 9 3 6 - -
    - L C M - -
```

How do I have to use it?

Comment: I think you have a digit typo in the code box.

Comment: No digit typo - I checked it many times. But your question leads to 2 points: 1. You are on the right way! 2. The text is important!

Comment: @Varon Ah, so you actually do know the answer! No more money troubles for you :p

Comment: @nine9: I repeated what a passerby said to me. Bad excuse.. I know ;)

Comment: @Varon Make sure to change your pin though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your pin is

> 9476

Argument:

> - The table lists the four digits (called $A,B,C,D$).
>  - The upper right triangle lists the digit sums of the greatest common divisors; for instance, the greatest common divisor of $B=4$ and $D=6$ equals $2$.
>  - The lower left triangle lists the least common multiples modulo $9$; for instance, the least common multiple of $B=4$ and $D=6$ is $12$, which yields $3$ when taken modulo $9$; similarly, the least common multiple of $C=7$ and $D=6$ modulo $9$ yields $6$.

Comment: Another way is to apply LCM again and again till you get a single digit. The pin is right anyway.